# Line 5: 'name' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: reactjs

```
export default class MapSet {

  constructor() {
    this._umap = new Map();
    for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(this._umap))) {
      let method = this._umap[name];
      if (!(method instanceof Function) || method === Map) continue;
      this[name] = function() {
        return method.apply(this._umap, arguments);
      };
    }
  }

  map(key, obj) {
    const act = this._umap.get(key);
    if (act) {
      act.add(obj);
    } else {
      this._umap.set(key, new Set([obj]));
    }
  }
}
```

I I don't quite understand why it went wrong ? work in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12117) in certain versions of ESLint. Updating ESLint to the latest version should fix it.

Note that if you're using create-react-app, the ESLint dependency there hasn't yet been updated to the latest one, so you might want to look into [overriding the dependencies](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) for it with yarn.

Comment: I took your approach, and it worked. I ran this command and put it here to share with others.`npm install babel-eslint eslint eslint-config-react-app eslint-loader eslint-plugin-flowtype eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks`